# Almacenar HTML en variable js desde una funcion callback dentro de una clase

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp

Me encontré código difícil de factorizar, mi intento de descomponer no resulto satisfactoria, a tal punto que junto con mi equipo llegamos a crear **HTML** ofuscado en **JavaScript**, es decir, etiquetas **HTML** almacenadas en variables de tipo `string`.

```
var html = $(
    '<div class="row">' +
    '    <div class="col-xs-12">' +
    // Mas Lineas de HMTL ofuscado
    '    </div>' +
    '</div>'
);
```

Para más adelante, llegó a ser un dolor de cabeza. Para resolver este problema tuve la idea de solicitar un documento html como un texto, dando el siguiente código

```
class Operacion 
{
    self = this;
    html = null;

    constructor() {
        this.ejecutar();
    }

    ejecutar() {
        $.ajax({ 
            type: 'GET',
            url: '../../Scripts/Site/Contratacion/Propietarios.html',
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (data) {
                self.html = $(data);
        });
        console.log(self.html); // undefined
    }
}
```

Me percate de que se trataba de una solicitud asíncrona, entonces vi el modo de obtener dicha variable con artificios de **jquery**

```
var a = function () { 
    $.get('../../Scripts/Site/Contratacion/Propietarios.html', (g) => { 
        self.html = g;
    })
}

$.when(a()).done(() => console.log(self.html)); // undefined
```

Respuesta a @JCAguilera -> Cuando solamente ejecuto el código:

```
$.get('../../Scripts/Site/Contratacion/Propietarios.html', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(typeof (data));
});
```

Obtengo el siguiente resultado en consola:

**Contratacion.js:2222:21**

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="box box-warning">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                Algunos Botones
            </div>
            <div class="box-body table-responsive">
                </br>
                <table id="tblCont" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    Algunos Datos
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Contratacion.js:2222:22**

```
string
```

> no estas equivocado el archivo "Contratacion.js" ya tiene mas de 2000 líneas de código

Sin embargo, no tuve resultados deseado. ¿Hay algún modo de almacenar html desde ajax?

Comment: En algunas partes de tu código confundes **hmtl** con **html**, revisa, por favor, si te equivocaste en el código original o sólo fue un error al escribir la pregunta.

Comment: Corregido gracias por tu observacón

Comment: ¿Qué te retorna el ajax exactamente? Haz un console.log(data) dentro de la función success del ajax y comparte lo que te salga en tu pregunta, por favor.

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera el tipo de dato que retorna es string dentro del callback `success`, lo cual me resulto interesante resolverlo por este medio

Comment: ¿HTML ofuscado? ¿Cuál es el objetivo? El inspector del navegador lo va a presentar muy bien estructurado.

Comment: @JCAguilera este es el resultado que obtengo, se antes de: "Sin embargo, ... desde ajax?"

Comment: @Triby Si, exacto, pero mi archivo Contratacion.js ya tiene mas de 2000 lineas de codigo, ya no es mantenible :(

Comment: @AlexandroArce, no sé exactamente cuál es la idea, pero casi estoy seguro que en lugar de llegar a una solución solo vas a complicar más lo que ya tienes.

Comment: @Triby Trato de refactorizar el codigo, buenas practicas de un programador, elemental a la hora de trabajar y automatizar el trabajo

Comment: si quieres otra pagina html simplemente agrega un link o carga la pagina y listo, estas trabajando de mas y no tiene ningun beneficio la manera en que estas llamando toda la pagina html para mostrarla

Comment: @MiguelZarate Quiero aclarate que no estoy llamando una pagina html, solo un una segmento de ella,

Comment: Vi tambien que Angular leé un archivo HTML desde el decorativo `@component` con la llave `'templateUrl'`, como lo hace angular?

Comment: pues 2000 lineas de codigo no parece que sea solo una parte, tal vez si expones mas sobre el codigo se pueda simplicar tus llamados.

Answer (score 0):

Una solucion muy poco práctica y peligrosa es definir la llave async como `false`, para obtener el archivo y poder asignar la variable como string, dando como ejemplo lo siguiente.

```
class OperacionesAsignacionMaquinaria
{
    self = this;
    plantillas = null;
    tabla = null;

    constructor() {
        this.ejecutar();
    }

    ejecutar(contenido) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (result) {
                self..html = $(result);

            },
            url: getAbsoluteUrl('/Scripts/Site/Operaciones/Contratacion/Propietarios/ModalMaquinaria.html'),
        });
    }
}
```

Obtienes el valor y guardas el archivo html por que basicamente se trata de un string. aunque otra solucion que tuve es guardar el contenido html en la base de datos, y solicitar cuando lo necesitaba